# Kubernetes helm - Running helm install in a running pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to spin up a single **installer pod** with `helm install` that once running, will apply some logic and install other applications into my cluster using `helm install`.

I'm aware of the helm dependencies, but I want to run some business logic with the installations and I'd rather do it in the **installer pod** and on the host triggering the whole installation process.

I found suggestions on using the Kubernetes REST API when inside a pod, but `helm` requires `kubectl` installed and configured.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `kubectl` to your **installer pod**.

"In cluster" credentials could be provided via service account in "default-token" secret: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/

Answer (score 8):

It seems this was a **lot** easier than I thought...

On a simple pod running Debian, I just [installed **kubectl**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/), and with the default service account's secret that's already mounted, the **kubectl** was already configured to the cluster's API.

Note that the configured default namespace is the one that my installer pod is deployed to.

Verified with

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
$ kubectl get ns
```

I then [installed **helm**](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#installing-helm), which was already using the **kubectl** to access the cluster for installing **tiller**.

Verified with

```
$ helm version
$ helm init
```

I installed a test chart

```
$ helm install --name my-release stable/wordpress
```

**It works!!**

I hope this helps

Comment: This method only works if role-based access control (RBAC) is disabled for the cluster

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is still actual but I've written a helm plugin which does exactly what is described in the question: https://github.com/noksa/helm-in-pod/

The plugin runs **any** command in a pod (helm install/kubectl get/etc)